# Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example :

**registry.html**

```
<label>Name:</label>
```

**app.js**

```
 define(['angular', 'services','text',
'text!ang/templates/registry.html'], function(angular, services,textmod,template) {
    ........
        angular.module('myApp.directives', ['myApp.services'])
        .directive('superd', function() {
                      return {

                               templateUrl:template,
                                   ..........
                                }
                })
```

Eror :

GET app_ang/%3Clabel%3EName:%3C/label%3E 403 (Forbidden)
angular.js?bust=1417672731204137.41101580671966:10023

Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:  `<label>Name:</label>`

Note : 'text' is https://github.com/requirejs/text

Comment: What is the value of "template" in your directive? is it dynamic, then where from that vale comes?

Comment: Did you try to access the page directly in browser? Also, look firebug for the request and copy that url and hit directly in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to depend on `'text'` directly.

```
define([
  'angular', 
  'services', 
  'text!ang/templates/registry.html'
], function(angular, services, template) {
  //...
  angular.module('myApp.directives', ['myApp.services'])
         .directive('superd', function() {
           return {
             templateUrl: template,
             //...
           };
         });
```

And in your require config:

```
require.config({
  //...
  paths: {
    // path example if you are using bower
    'angular': '/bower_components/angular/angular',
    'text': '/bower_components/requirejs-text/text'
  },

  shim: {
    'angular': {
      exports: 'angular'
    }
  }
});
```